# Ruby, Rspec, and yield stubbing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, yield

Let's say I have a class like this in Ruby:

```
class Test
  def execute
    count = 0
    40.times do
      search_for_names(count) do |name, last_name|
        yield name, last_name
      end
      count += 1
    end
  end

  def search_for_names(count)
    friend = get_friend_name(count)
    yield friend.name, friend.last_name
  end
end
```

My question is: how do I do to stub my search_for_names method to get 40 different names in my Rspec test? (I installed Faker).
I tried:

```
let(:friends) do
described_class.new
end

allow(friends).to receive(:search_for_names).and_yield(
      Faker::Name.name,
      Faker::Name.last_name
)

 it 'finds multiple friends' do
    friends.execute do |name, last_name|
      puts name
      expect(name).not_to be_empty
      expect(last_name).not_to be_empty
    end
  end
```

But it prints always the same name x40.

And... :

```
allow(friends).to receive(:search_for_names).and_yield(
      Faker::Name.name,
      Faker::Name.last_name
    ).and_yield(
      Faker::Name.name,
      Faker::Name.last_name
    )
```

But it prints two different names x40 (80 names). But I would like to have only 40 times a different name. Is it possible ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is `.and_yield(Faker::Name.name, Faker::Name.last_name)` is being executed *once*. Your function is *already* prepared to receive a param, use it:

```
40.times do |i|
  allow(friends).to receive(:search_for_names).with(i).and_yield(
    "#{Faker::Name.name}_#{i}",
    "#{Faker::Name.last_name}_#{i}"
  )
end
```

---

*Sidenote:* instead of introducing a local variable `count`, just use what `Integer#times` passes to the block:

```
def execute
  40.times do |count|
    search_for_names(count) do |name, last_name|
      yield name, last_name
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome !! Thanks a lot ! It works perfectly ! And thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use the block syntax of `receive` like so

```
allow(friends).to receive(:search_for_names) do |_,&block| 
  block.call(Faker::Name.name, Faker::Name.last_name)
end
```

rather than implicitly `yielding` to the block instead we capture the block (`&block`) and then explicitly call it with the `Faker` arguments.

This avoids the need for the internal loop 40 times to make `allow`ances as every time `search_for_names` is called this block will be executed again.

[Repl Example](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/AllowReceiveandBlock)